# A filtered and sorted view in CouchDB?

Tags: javascript, json, couchdb

I have some items in CouchDB with a `timestamp` field and a `group` field. I use this view function to get a list of all items where group == "foo":

```
{
  "map" : "function(doc) { emit(doc.group, doc); }"
}
```

`http://localhost:5984/my_database/_temp_view?key="foo"`

Now I'd like to make the output sorted by the `timestamp` field. How do I do that? Basically, I want the equivalent of this SQL query:

`SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE group=? ORDER BY timestamp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emit the timestamp as a second column:

```
function(doc) { emit([doc.group,doc.timestamp]); }
```

Then, query with the following parameters:

```
view?startkey=["foo"]&endkey=["foo",""]
```

I am assuming that your timestamps are numbers, not strings. Read [this](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_collation) to understand how the numeric timestamps will be sorted in-between `["foo"]` and `["foo",""]`.

Also, don't emit `doc` as the value, it uses a lot of storage. If you really need the document, use `include_docs=true` in your query.